# input searched dictionary python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, input

i want python to take an input from me (a shopping list) and it gives me back the input but sorted after the values of a dictionary.

```
locations = {'banana': 1, 'steak': 5, 'water': 9, 'cheese': 4, 'wine': 2, 'pizza': 8}
#today I want to buy banana and cheese
groceries = ['banana', 'cheese'] # this should be the input instead
groceries.sort(key = lambda x: locations[x])

for item in groceries:
   print('{} is located in area: {}'.format(item, locations[item]))
```

Output:

banana is located in area: 1

cheese is located in area: 4

What i want now is that the function 'groceries' will be an input. How can i manage this? Many thanks!!

Comment: I have a dictonary that tells which product i can find where in the store. I then want to enter a items i want to buy and python returns me the items sorted by their values.

Answer (score 0):

First note that `groceries` in your code is not a function! It is a list. What I understand from your question is that you want to make your code as a function that has an input. It is easy, just use the function's structure starting with `def ... ( ... ):` where the first dots should be replaced by name of your function and the second dots should be replaced by name of your inputs. And then just put your last three lines of code inside it as the body of your function. See Python's documentation page for "*how to define a function*" at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions. So here is how your code can become a function.

```
locations = {'banana': 1, 'steak': 5, 'water': 9, 'cheese': 4, 'wine': 2, 'pizza': 8}

def locator( groceries ):
    groceries.sort(key = lambda x: locations[x])
    for item in groceries:
        print('{} is located in area: {}'.format(item, locations[item]))
```

And here is how you will use it.

```
today_groceries = ['banana', 'cheese' ]
locator( today_groceries )
```

However, reading your comment below your own question, it seems you want a return value for your function and not printing those sentences. In that case, just use a return-line; `return( ... )` with dots replaced by what you want to return. If you want to receive the same list as the one you gave as an input, but just ordered according to their locations, then you don't even need the last two lines in your code.

```
def locator( groceries ):
    groceries.sort(key = lambda x: locations[x])
    return( groceries )
```

Now by asking `locator( ['cheese', 'banana'] )` you do not see anything printed in your terminal anymore. It returns `['banana', 'cheese']`. You can save it in a variable, do something with it or put it inside a `print`.